# Port selection not possible in Arduino IDE on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, arduino, upload

I have upgraded to 20.04. Arduino IDE loaded with:

```
snap install arduino
```

as suggested (version 1.8.13). The port selection item cannot be selected. As suggested in other posts, I have done:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Actually, this added `dialout` in groups. I rebooted, `dialout` is still in groups, but still the port cannot be selected and, of course, I cannot upload anything on Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved. The snap installation was not successful.

I went through the distro from Arduino, and found a nice file: `arduino-linux-setup.sh`. I have run `install.sh` as root, then:

```
arduino-linux-setup.sh $USER
```

as regular user and finally ports are visible and can be used.

I could not find any place where this procedure is suggested, not even from the Arduino web site, although they had for sure defined what is in `arduino-linux-setup.sh`.

I hope this is useful and will help also to solve problems for future distro.